# Oracle_Loader Quote in quoted field

Tags: oracle

I have a create table ext_file (....) type oracle_loader query that opens a text file to pull data out of it. The access parameters are:

```
records delimited by newline
fields terminated by '\t'
optionally enclosed by '\"'
ltrim
missing fields are null
```

The problem I just noticed is that one of the fields is height and it is stored in the text file as:

```
"5'6.35""
```

The use of a " inside a "-enclosed field without an escape is causing every record with height to be kicked out.

How can I tell oracle_loader to accept these values (and I really could care less if the " makes it in or if the field is trimmed to 5'6.35).

I have two solutions, neither of which are optimal:
1. Use sed to escape the " inside the " as \"
2. Omit the optionally enclosed by '\"' line, which will break lines in which the field terminator is inside a field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to move the enclosed by clause into each line instead of overall for the table. For example:

```
create table ext_tb (
    a varchar2(255),
    b varchar2(255),
    height varchar2(255)
) organization external (
    type oracle_loader
    default directory my_data_dir
    access parameters (
        records delimited by newline
        fields terminated by '\t'
        -- DO NOT add the enclosed line here
        lrtrim
        missing field values are null
        (
            a char optionally enclosed by '"',
            b char optionally enclosed by '"',
            height
        )
    ) location('my_file.ttx')
)
```

Now, that pesky height field will be in the database as "5'6.35"" (three double-quotes in it). You can run a query on the column to remove the quotes.